# Report Viewer after deploying on server

Tags: asp.net

An error occurred during local report processing.
The definition of the report 'D:\Inetpub\Vhosts\skyhighindustries.net\httpdocs\Sky\Report3.rdlc' is invalid.
An unexpected error occurred in Report Processing.
Access to the path 'D:\temp\expression_host_7fc1e8bf42474ccfb1dbd1c05ceaa6e5.dll' is denied.
Please help i m getting this error after deploying my report on server

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the identity that your application is using in IIS has at least browser access to your reporting services instance.